# Error: No \title given

Tags: titles, bookcover

I'm trying to use a standard cover page from the university for my thesis, but is giving an error: no \title given and I don't know why.

This is the code for the `\frontpage´ that I introduce in the main file.

```
% cover page generation
\newcommand{\frontPage}{
    \begin{titlepage}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{1cm}
            \includegraphics[width=3cm]{Logo_.png} \\[4ex]
            \textsc{\LARGE \textbf{University of}} \\[2ex]
            \textsc{\large \textbf{Department of Civil, Environmental and Architectural Engineering}} \\[2ex]
            PhD Course in Architectural and Civil Engineering 

            \vfill
            {\LARGE \textbf{\@title}}
            \vfill

            \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
                \begin{flushleft}
                    \centering
                    \textbf{Supervisor:} \\
                    Doctor \@supervisor \\
                    \textbf{Co-Supervisors:} \\
                    Doctor J u \\
                    Doctor J  S 
                    
                \end{flushleft}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}
                \begin{flushright}
                    \centering
                    \textbf{Author:} \\
                    \@candidate \\
                    (Ciclo XX)
                \end{flushright}
            \end{minipage}

            \vfill
            \textsc{Academic Year \@academicYear}
            \vspace{1cm}

        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
}
```

Comment: Two issues: 1. did you provide a `\title{your title}` command somewhere (with 'your title' replaced by your actual title)? 2. the code that you posted contains `@` signs, this only works when the code is either in a `.cls` or `.sty` file or, if it is in a `.tex` file, if it is surrounded by `\makeatletter` ad `\makeatother` commands.

Comment: @Marijn this code is in a .cls file, that is called in my main file in Overleaf. I have done ctrl+find  in all files for \title and  no match, so no, I don't have this command. I don't know how to overcome this error

Comment: If the error message says 'No \title given' and indeed you did not provide a title then (most likely) the solution is to provide a title. Practically: somewhere near the top of your document, before you call `\frontPage`, you should put a line containing `\title{This is the title of my thesis}`.

Comment: Thank you, did work, is because I had the command \@title, and no title so... and I couldn't find with ctrl+F because is \@title and not \title

Answer (score 0):

The frontpage has a command `\@title`, and I haven't defined a title before. So by adding `\title{Name}` it works.